# Creating a FB Notification for my app

Tags: javascript, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to create a notification for my app for when a user is added to a to do list item.

I want to post a message such as: "You have been added to THIS item on THIS app"

However, I cant seem to work out what API request to make and can only see how to send app invites.

The below code is my implementation but currently all it does is return how many notifications I have

```
fbAppNotification: function (user){

    for(var i = 0; i < user.length; i++){
        FB.api('/' + user[i] + '/notifications', function(response) {
            console.log(response);
            if(response.success === true){
                alert('yay');
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are making call in a wrong way, you have to provide other `parameters` such as app access token, template etc. and your app should be a `canvas app`

For more details go through the [Notifications API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/notifications/) tutorial on the developers site, they have elaborated how to use this API with example (quite simple)

Also you are making a GET request (which is by default) instead of `POST` (for which you have to mention the method explicitly) that's why instead of posting you are simply getting the result.

---

**Code Example**:

```
FB.api('/RECEIPIENT_USERID/notifications', 
       'post', 
       {
           access_token: APP_ACCESS_TOKEN,
           template: "You have been added to THIS item on THIS app",
           href: REDIRECT_URL        
       }, 
       function(response)
       {
          if (!response || response.error)
          {
             alert('Error occurred');
          } 
          else 
          {
             alert('Success :D');
          }
       }
);
```